# Need solution for this in javascript string reverse without inbuit function

Tags: javascript

I have below string

```
var str = 'ABC DEF GHI JKL';
```

I need after reversing this.

```
required string
'CBA FED IHG LKJ';
```

I have tried this

```
    var str = 'ABC DEF GHI JKL';

  for(var i=1;i<str.length;i++) {
    var j = 0;
    if(str[i] === ' ') {
        j = i;
        for(var k=j; k < j-1 ; k++) {
            var temp = str[k];
            str[k] = str[k+1];
            str[k+1] = temp;
        }
    }
  }
      document.write(str);
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance withour inbuilt function please

Comment: Then try writing something yourself first, and ask if you get stuck

Comment: Its not a free coding service. Post your effort!

Comment: Your attempt wont work because strings are immutable. You can't do `str[k] = str[k+1]`

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, suggest me other way

Comment: I did. Just read the linked question. :)

Comment: While this is a duplicate, answers on the other post do use the built in `reverse` array method so here's how I'd do it without in two steps.

1) Reverse the string recursively: 
`const reverse = ([head, ...rest]) => rest.length ? reverse(rest) + head : head;`

2) Split up your string, apply `reverse` to it, and join it up again:

`'ABC DEF GHI JKL'.split(' ').map(reverse).join(' ');`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is there any way to do without in built function

Comment: Oh, you need to put this requirement in the question title.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gudonecefo/edit?js,console

Comment: @YuryTarabanko question updated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reverse a string without using the built-in `reverse` method is to use recursion.

Then you can split your string into an array of strings based on spaces, reverse each portion, and re-join back into a string.

```
const reverse = ([head, ...rest]) => rest.length ? reverse(rest) + head : head;

'ABC DEF GHI JKL'.split(' ').map(reverse).join(' ');
```

https://jsbin.com/gudonecefo/edit?js,console

As a function:

```
const reverseWords = sentence => sentence.split(' ').map(reverse).join(' ')

reverseWords('ABC DEF GHI JKL') // 'CBA FED IHG LKJ'
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to convert the string to array then use loops. Reverse it, then convert it to string again and concatenate

```js
var str = 'ABC DEF GHI JKL';
var final_str = '';
var rev_str = [];
var split_str = str.split(" ");
split_str.forEach(function(element){
 var split_el = element.split("");
 var temp_rev = [];
 for (var i=split_el.length-1;i >= 0 ;i--){
   temp_rev.push(split_el[i])
 }
 rev_str.push(temp_rev)
})

rev_str.forEach(function(element){
    var str_n = element.join('') + ' ';
  final_str += str_n
})

document.write(final_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

`'13 213 abc'.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: Split and join on space :)

Comment: No not space @JohanKvint?!

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are after is something like this:

```
var str = 'ABC DEF GHI JKL';

function reverser(str) {
    // Split string on spaces and revers parts in split
    // Join back togehter with spaces
    return str.split(' ').map(partReverser).join(' ');
}

function partReverser(part) {
    // Split string to array and reverse
    // Join back together to string
    return part.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverser(str));
```

Comment: Any other way to do without in-built function?

Comment: Which function is not permitted? Just the reverse? or even split and join?

Comment: split, reverse, map and join, all the in built function.

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment :) I will leave that up to you to figure it out then

Comment: Try to implement the split, map, reverse and join yourself and the use the same pattern. Just a suggestion :)